# Simple Calculus Problem

Tags: calculus

The temperature on the coldest winter day in $2009$ is determined by $\frac{t}{20} * (t-12) * (t-24)$. If $t$ is measured in hours and $t=0$ is at midnight, which of the following is the average temperature between $7$am to $3$pm.

How is the answer not integral of $[\frac{t}{20} * (t-12) * (t-24)]$ from $7$ to $15$ which is about $50.8$?
The answer was like $6.35$? How??

Comment: Suppose this was a discrete question and you had the temperature $t_i$ at $N$ distinct time intervals, then the average would be:
$\frac{\sum_i t_i}{N}$. An integral is really just a sum in the discrete case, so what are you missing?

Comment: gotta divide by 8 thank you

Comment: It is not about $50.8$; it is exactly $50.8$. It is not like $6.35$; it is exactly $6.35$.

Answer (score 4):

You're being asked for the average, so divide it by the number of hours... You essentially are right at the finish line with your answer.

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/AvgFcnValue.aspx (for some extra reading)

Comment: O SHOOT I NEED TO DIVIDE BY 15-7=8. thank you